# How to download original source-code from chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an extension in Chrome Webstore I would like to download original files that used to be uploaded. Is there any direct way to download it straight from the store, since I am the creator and I do have access to my account?

Comment: There's probably no way because the web store recreates the CRX it offers when you upload something so there should be no need for them to keep the original.

Comment: @wOxxOm So the only way is to inspect it from the browser and copy the source?

Comment: That won't be the original source, that'll be the recreated one, AFAIK. You can download it directly, see [CRXviewer](https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer) extension's source code. There's also a [web store API `get` command](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the current / past version of an extension on https://chrome-stats.com/. You can also just inspect the source code directly on that website.